# Rewrite URL to remove query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL that needs to be reformatted. `example.com/?article_category=lifestyle` I want this to be formatted to: example.com/lifestyle. However, when I try to reformat it with my .htaccess file it doesn't work. My .htaccess file is located in the same directory as my file. The file name is index.php.

Here's the rewrite rule I proposed:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?article_category=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I don't know why this isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful Docs: [RewriteCond Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) & [RewriteRule Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article_category=([a-z]+)
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+) index.php?article_category=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Line 1: checking if query string containing `article_category=([a-z]+)`, `article_category=lifestyle` matched

Line 2: if the URL is `example.com` or `example.com/`, redirect permanently to `/lifestyle`, `%1` is a RewriteCond backreference, grouped parts (in parentheses `([a-z]+)`) of the pattern

Line 3 / 4: if the URL is not regular files and directories

Line 5: if the URL is starting with alphabetic, rewrite the URL to `index.php?article_category=$1`

Comment: This does work, but when I do example.com/lifestyle it redirects me to a 404. It's not reading the index.php file, if I do example.com/index.php?article_category=lifestyle it works How can I make it so example.com/lifestyle works from index.php?

Comment: And it also works for index.php/lifestyle, but not just example.com/lifestyle

Comment: just edited, you could have these rules to strip off the query string and make an redirect, and rewrite the URL to `index.php?article_category=`

Comment: Hmm, this is also affecting other index.php files from other directories...Is there a solution to just fix that specific index.php file in root?